# Gstreamer Multifilesrc loop short video

Tags: video, video-streaming, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0, python-gstreamer

I was wondering if it is possible to even get the multifilesrc to work. I am on the latest gstreamer version and cannot make a simple video loop. I've tried so many iterations of the above, to show a few:

```
gst-launch-1.0 multifilesrc location="./short.mp4" loop=TRUE index=0 ! decodebin ! autovideosink
gst-launch-1.0 multifilesrc location="./short.mp4" loop=TRUE ! decodebin ! autovideosink
gst-launch-1.0 multifilesrc location="./short.mp4" loop=true ! decodebin ! autovideosink
gst-launch-1.0 multifilesrc location="./short.mpg" loop=true ! decodebin ! autovideosink
```

Does anyone know what is missing to loop? I also added raw caps filtering to no avail. I can do it incredibly easily with an image on multifilesrc, but with video cannot get to work. I need the script to repeat the video file provided in a larger script, but cannot get it to work even at the most basic level.

According to https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/multifile/multifilesrc.html?gi-language=c, it should be possible on all media.

Comment: What is actually the error?

Comment: The error @FlorianZwoch is that it doesn't loop. After 10seconds (the video's length) the video just stops. So only one play is performed while I am hoping for a loop!

Answer (score 1):

`multifilesrc` element is not designed to replay video streams in loop. As per documentation, this element `Reads buffers from sequentially named files. [...] File names are created by replacing "%d" with the index using printf().`. So it can be useful to make a video out of images like `000.png` to `999.png` for example. WHen `loop=True` is used, the element will replay the stream from 000 to 999.

I don't think it's possible to loop video in GStreamer, see [Looping a video with gstreamer and gst-launch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6833147/looping-a-video-with-gstreamer-and-gst-launch)